# How to use multiple databases (MSSQL) in one service or DAL?

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, architecture

I have been looking through a few different threads all over the interwebs and either I can't see that the proposed solution will work for me, or their particular situations are not the same as the one I am in.

Currently with have about 8 or so different self contained databases, each sitting behind yet another self contained website (asp.net webforms). All of the databases are very small, and serve a very particular purpose. That said, none of the schemas and designs really match up in a reasonable way. There are various GUIDs that identified a user that will all EVENTUALLY map to a single guid for that user, but the mapping between them are different, and sometimes you have to hop between a couple databases to get what you need from a third. It's just a bit messy.

I would like to refactor completely to put them all in one database to reduce confusion and duplicate data, but due to push-back the solution will have to be use what we have.

What I want to do them is create a layer where all these databases will be accessible in ONE application (maybe fire up a new site and put it there). A few questions regarding this:

1. Is there a simple solution where I can leverage Entity Framework on each database and have them all sit in the same application?
2. Would something like a WCF service where I map every CRUD operation that needs to be done for each database be an efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each DBContext in Entity Framework uses a single database, so  your solution here must use one for each database. What I usually do is create an `IContext` around the `DBContext` that implements the CRUD operations, then build a `Repository` that performs the "business logic" (like `RegisterUser`) my manipulating multiple contexts. The IContext should represent a set of related "database objects" (such as IProductContext for the product database). For now, you would probably just have one context per database. As databases are consolidated, just change the connection string of the affected context(s) to the new database and you can get back up and running without much (if any) code changes.

Here's a good intro I found on what I'm talking about, though I think this calls my "Contexts" Repositories" and my "Repositories" "Unit of Work".
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

That said, you could probably write one WCF service that abstracts away multiple EF DBContexts, then you can change things on the backend while continuing to use the same webservice.

Comment: That should do the trick. I have dug into this pattern a little bit recently, so I think with some tweaking I should be able to get it to work.